# How can I adjust this carousel to only pause when user mouses over one of the boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I'm trying to alter this premade code so that it works for my website idea. I'm wondering how the 'pause' function can only be triggered upon the user mousing over one of the `li` items; otherwise, the carousel would loop forever.

How might this be achieved? I googled and was trying things like:

```
if ($('#element:hover').length != 0) {
    pause();
}
```

but this is not compliant with the code. Can I receive some assistance? Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/lovromar/Z4VpZ/

HTML

```
<div id="carousel-container">
    <div id="carousel-inner">
        <ul id="carousel-ul">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>                  
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#carousel-container {
    width: 680px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
}

#carousel-inner {
    width: 680px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#carousel-ul {
    position:relative;
    left:-160px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:9999px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

#carousel-ul li{
    float: left;                                    
    width: 150px;  
    padding:0px;
    height:186px;
    margin: 50px 15px 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    line-height: 186px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
var Carousel = new
function() {

    var wrapper = document.getElementById('carousel-container'),
        timer = null;

    var start = function() {

        doCarousel();
    };



    var sliding = function() {



        var item_width = $('#carousel-ul li').outerWidth() + 10;


        var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel-ul').css('left')) - item_width;


        $('#carousel-ul:not(:animated)').animate({
            'left': left_indent
        }, 2000, 'linear', function() {


            $('#carousel-ul li:last').after($('#carousel-ul li:first'));


            $('#carousel-ul').css({
                'left': '-160px'
            });
        });




    };

    var doCarousel = function() {

        timer = setInterval(sliding, 2000);


    };

    var pause = function() {

        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;


    };

    var resume = function() {

        doCarousel();


    };

    this.init = function() {

        start();


    };


}();

$(function() {

    Carousel.init();

});
```

Comment: what do you mean by this is not compliant with the code?

Comment: I just mean that it doesn't work. More failed attempts on this version: https://jsfiddle.net/Z4VpZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work.

I changed the way you declare your object and it works like that:

```
var Carousel = {
    timer :null,
  wrapper: null,
  init : function()
  {
        var self = this;
     this.timer = setInterval(function(){self.sliding();}, 2000);
  }, 
  sliding : function() {
        var item_width = $('#carousel-ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel-ul').css('left')) - item_width;
        $('#carousel-ul:not(:animated)').animate({
            'left': left_indent
        }, 2000, 'linear', function() {


            $('#carousel-ul li:last').after($('#carousel-ul li:first'));


            $('#carousel-ul').css({
                'left': '-160px'
            });
        })},
        pause : function() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);

        this.timer = null;


    },
    resume : function() {
        this.init();
    },

};

$(function() {
    alert("init");
    Carousel.init();
    $('#carousel-ul li').mouseover(function(){ 
    //clearInterval(timer);
    //timer = null;
    //pause();
    Carousel.pause();
});
 $('#carousel-ul li').mouseout(function(){ 
    //clearInterval(timer);
    //timer = null;
    //pause();
    Carousel.resume();
});



});
```

Here is your Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Z4VpZ/4/

Usually, I avoid using Javascript function to declare classes, I make use of js object `{}`, or I use the [ECMASCRIPT 6 class statement](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-ecmascript-6-class-inheritance/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like that ?

```
$("#carousel-ul li").mouseover(function(){ Carousel.pause();});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, at least the way I'm doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/Z4VpZ/1/ What could be going wrong?